# User-defined type not defined on Word to Excel function

Tags: vba, ms-word

A nice user has supplied me with a better solution to my already existing code but does not work within Word. I'm trying to open an excel document when a user clicks a button. There are multiple buttons that open the same document but I want it to change the worksheet if the document is already opened and not another instance of the document. The following gives me the error:

> User-defined type not defined

```
Option Explicit

Public objExcel As Object

Sub Main()


    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

End Sub

'==================================================================

Public Sub QE1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        Main
    End If

    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("H:\My Documents\Flowchart to Word\Quality and Environmental management system flowchart.xlsm")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Project enquiry")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If sht Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Workbook doesn't have a sheet named 'Project enquiry'", vbCritical, "Sheet critical error"
    Else
        sht.Activate
    End If

End Sub
```

Unsure on why this does not work

Answer (score 0):

In general, `Workbook` and `Worksheet` are unknown objects for Word. Thus, you have to define them with `Excel.` like this:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
```

In general, `wb As Workbook` works pretty well, when the VBA code is in Excel, because then Excel is the default environment. But in Word, you have to specify it explicitly. Make sure that you add `Microsoft Excel 1N.0 Object Library` from VBEditor> Extras> Libraries:

[image]

---

If you want to make it a bit easier, define `wb` and `sht` as `Object`. This is called "late binding" and is a bit slower.

Comment: That was my first thought but still no luck. I have even tried putting the code in a new document and checking the button names but it's all fine on that side

Comment: @S.T - where (on which line) is the error happening?

Comment: @S.T - see the edit, it should work after adding the library.

Comment: @Viyata After the error it highlights the 'Dim wb As Workbook' and directs to the Sub Click button. Trying to access libraries from word, the 'references' option to get there is greyed out. Would like to assign these macros to the document itself so having it work only on mine might not be the best solution. Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: @S.T - what do you mean `greyed out`? If you close `Excel` and then open it and then try again, would they still be `greyed out`?

Comment: See I'm doing it from Word, the references option is greyed out and does not let me select it. Accessing this from Excel however does but the library you shown is already selected

Comment: @S.T - then simply dim `wb` and `sht` as `object` (`Dim wb as Object, sht as Object`) and give it a try.